# Basic EJB3 project doesn't work. NameNotFound Exception

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly

The server side contains the only interface and bean `@Remote` and `@Stateless` annotated.

Has ran on WildFly successfully, i can see deployed beans from WildFly console.

It's hints to me uri for JNDI bindings:

```
java:app/server_ejb/DeployBean!interfaces.Deploy
```

*But i can't connect to this!*

So my client is:

Initial context properties:

```
Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
Context.PROVIDER_URL=http-remoting://localhost:8080
```

Client:

```
Properties props = new Properties(...);
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
Deploy bean = (Deploy) ctx.lookup("java:app/server_ejb/DeployBean!interfaces.Deploy");
bean.sayHi();
```

I get an exception:

```
INFO: JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: app/server_ejb/DeployBean!interfaces.Deploy -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.app.server_ejb."DeployBean!interfaces.Deploy"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
```

wtf? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wildfly, for remote access to EJBs, you use the **ejb:** namespace with the following syntax:

**For stateless beans:**

```
ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>
```

**For stateful beans:**

```
ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>?stateful
```

See also: [EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)